# BT Home Hub 3.0A Local Network Unreachable

Tags: wireless-networking

I have three computers linked via wireless to a BT Home Hub 3.0A (as reported by the router config page). I would like the computers to be able to network to each other. The IP addresses are shown as being connected to the access point. None of the PCs are able to see the others IP addresses. There is an assortment of hardware: Raspberry Pi running Raspbian, an Acer Aspire 3600 running Ubunto 12.04 and a Dell Latitude E6410 running Windows 7. All of them are connected correctly to the Internet. I have set up port forwarding on the Pi, and am able to SSH to it via its external name.

I suspect this is something to do with my router configuration, but I haven't found anything useful in my research so far. Any help would be greatly appreciated. I have just turned it off and on again, with no change in behaviour.

Edit - now the two linux PCs can see each other after the reboot, and the Windows PC can see them, but the Pi cannot see the Windows PC.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem; restarted hub, all worked.

Comment: Keep the cursing out of the StackExchange network, please. We are a website targeted towards professionals